# Multiple solidity compiler versions in PATH

Tags: solidity

I have a mac and want to have different versions of the solidity compiler 8.7, 8.0, 7.6, 7.5 in PATH.

I installed solc accordingly to:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/installing-solidity.html#macos-packages
and I tested it from terminal with:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/solidity/0.8.15/bin/solc --version
solc file is 13.8 MB big

I downloaded stand alone compiler from https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/download/v0.7.6/solc-macos
it is 33,8 MB big and I get error "command not found" when I run:
sudo ./solc-macos --version

What do I have to do to work with solc-macos CLI? I think that I have to install it or extract... because only all together "solc", "solidity-upgrade", "yul-phaser" should have ~33,8 MB...

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to mac and it was necessary to make the binary executable by running: chmod 755 ${HOME}/bin/binary

Source:
https://zwbetz.com/how-to-add-a-binary-to-your-path-on-macos-linux-windows/